# Attempt 1 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: TELEGRAM API TELETHON

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon, py-telegram-bot-api

following code is producing error:

```
    import socks
import logging
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
api_id = 23982523
api_hash = '468f15380793hd40b9071e2379d08359'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
client = TelegramClient('mysession',
    api_id, api_hash,
    #proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, 'PROXYHOST', PROXYPORT, 'PROXYUSERNAME', 'PROXYUSERNAMEPASS')
)
client.start()
for message in client.iter_messages('chatname'):
    client.download_media(message)
```

error:

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using proactor: IocpProactor
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connecting to 149.154.167.91:443/TcpFull...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 1...
WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Attempt 1 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 2...
```

what is the solution?
NOTE: I'M in PAKISTAN, Telegram is banned here. so, I USED vpn but still not working. Few hours back same vpn and same code was working. Is it due to more attempts or any updates has affected it ? what is the reason? what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The library is unable to establish a connection to the Telegram servers (the socket operation is timing out, meaning it's unable to connect within a reasonable time).

The reason likely is Telegram servers cannot be reached from where you are.

The solution is to attempt connection via somewhere else (e.g. proxies).

Comment: i am using vpn but still getting same error